# how to supress User Account Control

Tags: c#, windows-10

SO I create an app. Every time an user opens the app... they get this popup. Can I suppress that? can It be suppress with publishing the app. If so, how does one do that

[image]

Comment: This is a Windows security feature to help protect against malware. If it could be suppressed within the application's code, wouldn't all malware take advantage of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the microsoft website

> To become a "known publisher," you need to purchase a digital certificate from a root CA; IIRC, the cheapest ones are ~$100/yr, with the VeriSign ones at ~$400/yr (which Microsoft prefers). Then sign the installer with the certificate.

So no, there is nothing you can do from within your code to change this